# Why doesn't electron's magnetic dipole rotate instead of precessing?

Tags: magnetic-fields

Precession of an electron in an external magnetic field is generally explained with a comparison to a spinning top/gyroscope, but these are fixed on one end and their movements are limited.

[image]

I could nowhere find an explanation why a free electron's magnetic dipole doesn't simply rotate and align itself with B. Can you please  explain why?

Comment: @Countto10, the question you link has absolutely nothing to do with this one: the electron here is not in an atom. and the values are not involved. The question is why doesn't it rotate and align itself (anti/parallel is not relevant)

Comment: conservation of angular momentum?

Comment: In a ferromagnetic crystal the atom is fixed to a location from which it cannot move away, and neither do its electrons and thus they can only "pivot". Conservation of angular momentum implies precession.

Comment: Thanks for asking the question (because I learnt something) and apologies for rushing in earlier with a niave comment. Next time, I might stick to my user name.

Comment: "the electron here is not in an atom."  The B direction is fixed in your graph. As for your proposal, it needs a check by somebody more familiar with the subject. anyway it is another question. Conservation of angular momentum explains the precession  not the quantum details

Comment: @annav, thanks, can you expand on that in an answer? in a gyroscope there is a point when gravity overcomes the resistance of L and it tumples down, isn't it the same when force is magnetic and not gravitational?

Comment: @annav, thanks, can you expand on that in an answer? in a gyroscope there is a point when gravity (or a push) overcomes the resistance of L and it rotates andtumbles down, isn't it the same when force is magnetic and not gravitational? Isn't there a B force so great to make the dipole rotate?